# How to secure iframe access of a secured domain from a non secure domain?

Tags: security, iframe, cross-domain

I am having two domains.One is secured and the other is not.Currently,when the user submits form data i redirect the the user to this secure website to collect further details.This redirection is made secure by means of cross domain cookies.

Now,instead of redirecting to the secure page i am planning to load the secure page in an iframe.But i am not aware of the security measures to be taken up to secure this communication via iframe.How to ensure that this communication is secured?Will setting cross-domain cookies solve the problem?

Comment: When you say that one domain is secured and redirection is secured by "cross domain cookies", secured how? When you say "secure this communication via iframe", what are your concerns?

Comment: Measures to prevent XSS and other attacks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I send a pixel request from non-secure to secure site,which inturn drops a cookie with its domain and sends back the pixel as mean of successful response. Now when the real request comes from non-secure site, i check for the cookie and it's domain therby creating a secure environment and also made the page in secure site a one time vist page.